# Is it feasible to mix static "label" values with data-bound values in a DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I need to display a grid comprised of static "label" values along with their corresponding data-bound values. IOW, something like so:

```
Label1  <Val1>  Label13 <Val13> . . .Label85    <Val85>
Label2  <Val2>  Label14 <Val14> . . .Label86    <Val86>
. . .
Label12 <Val12> Label24 <Val24> . . .Label96    <Val96>
```

I would like to use a DataGridView, if possible/feasible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

you can add dynamically label and in databound event set value bound of your label.
Set all your bounded value in a datatable, it will help you to set correct value on this event.

```
 protected void gdvCustomer_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        { 
            AddLabel(); 
        } 


        ///  
        /// Add a Label To GridView Row. 
        ///  
        private void AddLabel() 
        { 
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gdvCustomer.Rows) 
            { 
             a++;//row number
                if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
                { 
                    for (i =0;iyou can also take value from a datatable 
                    //or lb.Text = yourdatatable.Rows[a][i]; 
                    row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(lb); 
                    }
                } 
            } 
        }
```

Comment: happy to help you  my friend ;-)

Comment: I do not see a DataBound() event for DataGridView; the closest thing I see is DataBindingComplete() ... ?

Comment: it is for web control gridview here an url (rowdatabound):http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx